# Найти и загрузить CSS файл

Tags: php, css

Есть CSS с окончанием `'-responsive'`.
Как сделать так, чтоб при определенном условии загружались все CSS с окончанием `'-responsive'`?

Что-то вроде такого:

```
if ($this->getParam('addextracss',1) {
            $this->addCss ($name.'-responsive', false);
        }
```

Или такого:

```
if ($this->getParam('addextracss',1) {
                $this->addStyleSheet($name.'-responsive');
        }
```

Comment: if (что-то = true) { загрузить все css с окончанием '-responsive' }  else { загрузить что-то другое }

Comment: Используйте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php для нахождение всех файлов по шаблону.

Comment: @Visman это неудобно если css файлы раскиданы по директориям

Comment: все css находятся в одной директории и в одной папке и загружаются все они в function addHead()

Comment: @Blacknife, http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php#106595

Comment: @Visman это то и ежу понятно, но я например привык работать в больших проектах, не шерстить же все директории в нём?

Comment: @Blacknife, если стили разбросаны по всему проекту, то это кривой проект ;)

Comment: @Visman очень ошибочное мнение, модульная архитектура надеюсь вам знакома)

Comment: все css находятся в одной директории и в одной папке

Comment: @Сергей очень хорошо, можно спокойно использовать glob

Answer (score 0):

Как и говорили в комментариях используй функцию `glob`, а ты писал, что используешь функцию `addHead`

```
function addStyleSheet($mask = '-responsive.css') {
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/путь к папке/"; // лучше вынести за метод
   foreach (glob($path.'/*'.$mask, GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
       $this->addHead($file); // в $file к тебе приходит полный путь, уже смотри как тебе удобнее 
   }
}

if ($this->getParam('addextracss',1) {
     $this->addStyleSheet();
}
```